# How can I connect to a KeyVault without storing credentials?

Tags: azure, security, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

My web application has a number of secure configuration elements stored in a KeyVault. In order to connect to it, we have some code which uses an app Id and key, which in turn, because they allow access to the Key Vault, are secure credentials.

Can I connect to the KeyVault in some Integrated Security fashion, using the identity of the application as the credential? Or is there some other way to secure these credentials?

I've looked at protecting the config elements with encryption, but then there's another asset (the key) that has to be maintained, secured and deployed. That's better than plaintext config, but I'm trying to figure out the best solution here.

Comment: You want to get access to your key vault from Web App using the App Service or from a VM?

Comment: From a web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get access to Key Vault from a Web App using Azure Active Directory you can do the following

1. Go to your Web App
2. Go to Managed service identity and register the web app with Azure Active Directory (click `On` button and `Save` later), which is going to create the managed service identity.
   [image: Managed service identity]
3. Now go to the key vault and open `Access policies` tab
4. Click Add new
5. Select `Secret Management` as Configure from template
6. In Select principal option select the managed service identity was
   created for your web app (should be name as your app)
   [image]
7. Now go to Key permissions and at least select `Get`, to get access to
   your keys (same procedure for Secrets and Certificates).

Once you have done all these steps you can go to your web app code and get, eg, a secret as I show below:

```
AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

 var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

 var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

You are going to need to install `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` and `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault` NuGet packages to your application.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is running in a Web App, [Managed Service Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity) gives your app an identity that you can use to access Key Vault and other resources using AAD.